# What is the meaning of "smart padded"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

What is the meaning of "smart padded" in the following sentence?

> a woman in a smart padded coat along the stands,...

Would anyone give me simple explanation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Smart is likely describing the coat, not the padding. (Smart, in this case, is a chiefly British usage that means fashionable or nice-looking.) If "smart" were modifying "padded," there would be a hyphen between them denoting a compound adjective (smart-padded coat).

Comment: *Smart* may be more common in BrE, but it far from uncommon in AmE.

Answer (score 2):

> **[smart](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/smart)** (adj): 1.1 attractively neat and stylish.
>
> **[padded](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pad)** (adj):  1. Filled or covered with a soft material in order to protect or shape it or to make it more comfortable.

It's a good idea to use English language dictionaries to check the meaning of words you don't understand, rather than translation dictionaries.  These dictionaries might help you relate different English words to each other, which helps to improve your fluency.

In this case a "smart, padded coat" is a coat of *stylish* appearance, with some layers of extra cloth to either enhance the shape, or to make it warmer.

Comment: I strongly support what Andrew said about the desirability for English learners to use English dictionaries rather than translation dictionaries.